# EPOLLPRI when does this case happen?

Tags: epoll

When I set my epoll option, I can see EPOLLPRI.

It expalins there is urgent "read" required.

When does this actually occur?

Is there any way to send in that PRI Mode?

Answer (score 7):

`EPOLLPRI` in `epoll(7)` as well as `POLLPRI` in `poll(2)` is used to receive these urgent data.

Sometimes it's necessary to send high-priority (urgent) data over a connection that may have unread low-priority data at the other end. For example, a user interface process may be interpreting commands and sending them on to another process through a stream connection. The user interface may have filled the stream with as yet unprocessed requests when the user types a command to cancel all outstanding requests. Rather than have the high-priority data wait to be processed after the low-priority data, you can have it sent as out-of-band (OOB) data or urgent data.

[A Socket-based IPC Tutorial](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~singh/CIS725/Fall99/programs/sock_ipc_tut.html#TRANSFERRING)

To send OOB specify `MSG_OOB` flag in `send(2)`.

Comment: Link gets me access denied. I wonder if it's the same content as: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnx_4.25_docs/tcpip50/prog_guide/sock_ipc_tut.html